# Query an array of field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document:

```
{
  _id : objectId,

  field : [
           '1', 
           '2'
          ]
}
```

Desired query :

```
db.collection.find( { field : ['1','2'] },{ _id : 1 } )
```

Trying to retrieve the _id based on the field array

Comment: what exactly your question?

Comment: If I give a single value in `.find( { field : '1' },{ _id : 1 } )`, able to get _id, But I am trying to get the _id based on the array values `.find( { field : [ '1', '2' ] },{ _id : 1 } )`. Is this possible?

Comment: use $in cf https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: @felix thanks, but _$all_ is more preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ***[$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)*** to match the values.

```
db.collection.find( { field: { $all: [ '1','2' ] } }, { _id : 1 }  )
```

Comment: accurate answer. Thanks.